# Failed connection for mysql with Node application with correct password

Tags: mysql, node.js, server

I'm getting the following error when my application makes a create query:

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
   at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)`

When trying to get information from the database, I get nothing. And when using the command line to access mysql, it no longer asks me for a password, I just type `mysql` and it grants me access. This seems like it should not be the case.

I'm sure this is something to do with the sequel database configuration somewhere on the server, as this used to work on the same mysql instance on the server and also works locally for my development environment.

Both the node application and the mysql implementation are on the same server. They share the same localhost. I have ensured that my password is correct for the node mysql connection.

Here are the values I've set in my my.cnf file within `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
port=3306
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact root path, but after removing mysql, and making sure there was not an install history path left. Reinstalling and user the socket path instead of port was the way to go for Centos 7 + MySql 8